# Dropdown no navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, dropdown

Preciso de uma força aqui para um problema que esta me matando.

Não consigo dar ação no `dropdown` no meu **navbar**. Estou usando o Bootstrap 4.0 e jQuery 3.2.1. Seguem meus códigos:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="publicidade.php">
  <img src="img/home.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Inicio
 </a>
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown
 </a>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
 </div>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="relatorioChamados.php">
  <img src="img/consultar.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Relatórios Chamados
 </a>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="sair.php">
  <img src="img/off.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Sair
 </a>
</nav>

<script>
 $(function()){
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinha um erro na onde era fechado a `function()`, ou seja, um parenteses sem necessidade o correto está no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="publicidade.php">
  <img src="img/home.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Inicio
 </a>
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown
 </a>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
 </div>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="relatorioChamados.php">
  <img src="img/consultar.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Relatórios Chamados
 </a>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="sair.php">
  <img src="img/off.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  Sair
 </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Puts cara que vacilo, obrigado!!!

Comment: @GabrielBarreto se for útil poderia aceitar como resposta